# datareport count rows with certain value

Tags: sql-server, report

I have a stored procedure which selects columns from multiple tables. 
what i want is to be able to get the number of rows with values Y and number or row if value N that are in the returned records.
Example

```
name    availableYN
john     y
gary     n
mark     y
```

I want to be able to have that result and also a count like

```
y   2
n   1
```

any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: `select availableYN,count(availableYN) cnt 
from @temp
group by availableYN`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**COUNT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

```
SELECT
    availableYN,
    COUNT(availableYN) AS cnt
FROM
    My_Table
GROUP BY
    availableYN
```